# How to make navbar items not fall into new line on small screen in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make a responsive bootstrap navbar but not to collapse it. I want the item in navbar still stay in line even on small screen.

Here is my current navbar:

```
<nav id="topbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active d-flex align-items-center">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="tobar-text">Brand</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="tobar-text">Link 1</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="tobar-text">Link 2</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-nowrap">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have tried to set margin, padding, and whatever, but still it did not help. The items in navbar still fall into new line, I don't know why. Please kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in navbar goes to new line is because of `flex-direction: column`. You can use the flex utility as below.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-row">
```

Comment: one plus, thanks very much it's kind of working fine, but there is an offset from the top on small screen I don't know where it was from though I set margin-top and padding-top could not fix.

Comment: oh I found because the offset is from because I set the height to class `navbar-nav`. After I remove height, the item is perfectly centered the navbar on small screen. Thank very much :)

Comment: it's very kindness of you :)

Comment: @ Ismailvittal I could not find answer without your help in here, even I tried to google already. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thank you so much  @HouyNarun :) and glad to be part of the Stackoverflow community.

Comment: wow, after a long search, the solution is simple, thanks!